# Why is the answer to: How many ways to write a 15 bit string with at least 3 1s

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

I was going over my textbook to review permutations and combinatorics, which I have great difficulty comprehending despite seeming simple and came across this problem.

**How many ways are there to write a length 15 string using binary if there must be exactly 3 "1's" and 12 "0's".**

The answer to the problem was **C(15, 3)** or **C(15, 12)**. Now, I understand why there are two possible solutions to the problem, but I'm puzzled as to *why* the answer is C(15, 12) || C(15, 3)

From my understanding, we're choosing three (or twelve) of the digits to be 1 (or 0), which is good and all, but how does that ensure that the remaining digits are the remainings 0's or 1's?

tl;dr: By using C(15,3) we ensure that we have the # of ways three digits will be 1, but how does that guarantee the remaining 12 will be 0s?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to first principals:

- Start with all 15 bits set to 0 [1 way to do this]
- Choose 1 bit and flip it [15 ways to do this]
- Choose a different bit and flip it [14 ways to do this]
- Choose yet another bit and flip it [13 ways to do this]

It should be clear that exactly 3 bits are 1's and the remaining 12 are 0's

Total number of ways to do this: 1 x 15 x 14 x 13 = C(15, 3)